# Exclude file from jar as built by jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

My `pom.xml` contains the following to create a jar of my project with all dependencies.
Now I have a properties file in `src/main/resources` which is necessary to run the application (and I want to use it from starting from the IDE), but I do not want to ship it in the created jar file, as the settings are maintained separately.

**Question**: How I can I get a file with all dependencies, but exclude those properties files?

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>x.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why are you using the *maven-assemby-plugin* to build the JAR instead of the standard *maven-jar-plugin*?

Comment: @aribeiro because the jar plugin will only package the project artifacts (code and resources) without its dependencies, the OP requires an uber/fat jar instead

Comment: @A.DiMatteo thanks for the enlightenment. My eyes got stuck on the "don't want to ship the properties" part and didn't pay attention to the "dependencies" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with maven-assembly-plugin you can use an assembly descriptor file where you configure your filters, like in this section:

```
<fileSets>
<fileSet>
  <directory>${basedir}</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>*.txt</include>
  </includes>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>*.properties/exclude>
  </excludes>
</fileSet>
```

And in your maven configuration, pom.xml you specify the assemblu descriptor file, in the *descriptors* tag (distribution.xml is a file containing the section from above)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <filters>
        <filter>src/assembly/filter.properties</filter>
      </filters>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Also check this link [maven-assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html)

Comment: Indeed, that's the way to go if you want to keep on using the assembly plugin, I missed the point it was a file from the current project and not from an external dependency. Good point, plus1!

Comment: Thanks. Also, thanks for sharing your solution with shade plugin. Might help  in future.

Answer (score 5):

As specified by the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) documentation:

> If your project wants to package your artifact in an uber-jar, the assembly plugin provides only basic support. For more control, use the **Maven Shade Plugin**.

---

Using the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) you can have a fat jar (like using the assembly plugin) and solve similar issues of excluding files via configuration (no need of external assembly descriptor file).

In your case, to exclude resources from assembled jars, you can use [shade filters](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html).

A simple configuration would look like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*file_pattern*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the example above, you can customize `file_pattern` or narrow down your filter in the `artifact` element using your `my.groupId:my.artifactId`.

---

Note: the approach above is recommended when excluding files from external libraries, however you can still use the `maven-assembly-plugin` for excluding files from your own project via a custom [assembly descriptor](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) file.

Comment: Thanks. Heard of shade before - will look into it next!

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky I just realized (my bad) you wanted to exclude a file from your own project and not from an external dependency. You may still use the assembly plugin for that, please share as part of the question the assembly descriptor you are currently using in order to provide both options

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem (I had a checkstyle-config.xml that, should not be included in the final assembly). A solution below worked for me:
Adding the **resources** section made my project-jar-with-dependancies.jar not containing checkstyle-config.xml file

Simplified pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>checkstyle-config.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```