# Maven: How to exclude an artifact from fat-jar?

Tags: maven

I know about the `<exclusions>` attribute that is placed inside a `<dependency>` to exclude specific artifacts from a dependency but the problem with this is that one has to find out all the dependencies that might have the artifact that is desired to be excluded and then one by one exclude that artifact from all those dependencies. Isn't there a simpler way of specifying in the pom that a certain artifact should not end up in the fat-jar no matter what dependency is trying to include it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude file from jar as built by jar-with-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566217/exclude-file-from-jar-as-built-by-jar-with-dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-shade-plugin-1.4/examples/includes-excludes.html) and [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html)

Use artifactSet exclusions:

```
<artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                  <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                  <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                  <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
```

and also use filters to exclude classes:

```
<filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
                  <includes>
                    <include>junit/framework/**</include>
                    <include>org/junit/**</include>
                  </includes>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org/junit/experimental/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>org/junit/runners/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
```

Comment: that's a copy/paste answer, consider describing it (using filters, excludes, wildcards, etc)